# Incorrect Service Networking config for instance: xxxx:SERVICE_NETWORKING_NOT_ENABLED

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, google-cloud-sql, terraform-provider-gcp, google-vpc

I'm trying to replicate a SQL instance in GCP via terraform. The active instance has a public IP, however subnets from a secondary project are shared with the project hosing the SQL instance, and the SQL instance is associated with the secondary project's network.

I've added the `private_network` setting properly (I think) in the `ip_configuration` section, however I'm getting the following error:

> Error: Error, failed to create instance xxxx: googleapi: Error 400: Invalid request: Incorrect Service Networking config for instance: xxxx:xxxxx:SERVICE_NETWORKING_NOT_ENABLED., invalid

I can't find much documentation when I google that particular error, and I'm relatively new to Terraform, so I'm hoping someone can point out what I'm missing from either this section of my Terraform config, or another resource altogether.

```
resource "google_sql_database_instance" "cloudsql-instance-qa" {
  depends_on       = [google_project_service.project_apis]
  database_version = "MYSQL_5_7"
  name             = "${var.env_shorthand}-${var.resource_name}"
  project          = var.project_id
  region           = var.region

  settings {
    activation_policy = "ALWAYS"
    availability_type = "ZONAL"

    backup_configuration {
      binary_log_enabled             = "true"
      enabled                        = "true"
      point_in_time_recovery_enabled = "false"
      start_time                     = "15:00"
    }

    crash_safe_replication = "false"
    disk_autoresize        = "true"
    disk_size              = "5003"
    disk_type              = "PD_SSD"

    ip_configuration {
      ipv4_enabled    = "true"
      private_network = "projects/gcp-backend/global/networks/default"
      require_ssl     = "false"
    }

    location_preference {
      zone = var.zone
    }

    maintenance_window {
      day  = "7"
      hour = "4"
    }

    pricing_plan     = "PER_USE"
    replication_type = "SYNCHRONOUS"
    tier             = "db-n1-standard-1"
  }
}
```

Comment: You are defining both a public IP address (`ipv4_enabled    = "true"`) and private (`private_network = "projects/gcp-backend/global/networks/default"`). Use one or the other but not both.

Comment: @JohnHanley I set `ipv4_enalbed` to `false` but am still getting the same error. Do I need to update a setting somewhere else? The current, active/working, instance was both a public and private IP, and it's associated with the network in the secondary project.

Comment: Are you trying to specify a network in a different project?

Comment: @JohnHanley yeah, it's the default network in another project

Comment: I am fairly certain you cannot specify a network in a different project. When I enable Private IP in the GUI, I can only select a network in the current project.

Comment: Hm... On the active instance if I look at the `Associated networking` section of the SQL instance in the UI (it's on the `Overview` tab) I see the same value I have in the `private_network` section above.

Comment: I also forgot that you will also need to set up "Private service access".

Comment: I think you have an additional problem. Do you have the "Service Networking API" enabled? https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/library/servicenetworking.googleapis.com

Comment: @JohnHanley that was it, ty!

Answer (score 34, accepted):

If you see the following error:

> Error: Error, failed to create instance xxxx: googleapi: Error 400:
> Invalid request: Incorrect Service Networking config for instance:
> xxxx:xxxxx:SERVICE_NETWORKING_NOT_ENABLED., invalid

Enable the Service Networking API:

```
gcloud services enable servicenetworking.googleapis.com --project=[PSM_PROJECT_NUMBER]
```

[Getting Started with the Service Networking API](https://cloud.google.com/service-infrastructure/docs/service-networking/getting-started)

Comment: How does one achieve this via Pulumi/Terraform? Enabling features one by one manually is a pain!

Comment: @RounakDatta - Create a new question.

Comment: @RounakDatta not sure if you created a new question as John suggested but for posterity, in Pulumi you'd use: https://www.pulumi.com/registry/packages/gcp/api-docs/projects/service/ from the GCP provider.

Comment: Thanks, yes I was able to get this done seamlessly using the package you mentioned.